# How to remove the angular component once it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a button which when clicked goes to new Route and opens another component attached to that Route.

Is there a way in angular to remove the component from DOM which we are clicking to go to the different component?
Example: When the button 'Click Me to go to home' is clicked it opens another component.
And in this case once the new component is opened, remove the 'Click Me to go to home' button from the DOM. But should be added back when I am navigating from the next component by hitting some back button.

Here is the [code working in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-simplest):

HTML :

```
<button (click)=goTo()>Click Me to go to home</button>
```

TS:

```
goTo() {
    // to hide the URL from being visible
    this.router.navigate(['/home'], { skipLocationChange: true });
  }
```

Route:

```
const appRoute: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use *ngIf or [hidden] to hide the button if a condition is true and set the condition to true when the button is clicked.

Comment: That was the easiest solution, I couldn't think through earlier. Thank you so much for your help Steve.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it the right way using two components, you can more logically add a path in your appRoutes this way :

```
const appRoute: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: ClickButtonComponent},
 { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}
]
```

and only let your default root directive < router-outlet > in your app.component.html handle the navigation from the ClickButtonComponent to your HomeComponent :)

You can add your "back button" in home component with a function that calls the router to navigate to the first component (click-button) this way `this.router.navigate(['/']);`

Comment: In my project currently that's how I am doing. Thank you for your time and inputs. :)